# How to go to different page from one register form in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, registration

Hi I am beginner in codeigniter and have one question about form in codeigniter. I have 3 items that if click on If you register in site go to destination.But if dont register first he must register then redirect to the page he want.But i cant go to different page.
 my view:

```
<div class="row"><!--row of kol-->


        <br/>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2"></div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8" 
        style="border:1px solid black;">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">

        <div class="col-md-5"style="border:1px solid gray;">
        <form class method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/verifylogin">
            <div class="form-group">
               <label>username</label>
               <input class="form-control" id="namekarbari" name="namekarbari" 
               autocomplete="off"
               value="<?php echo set_value('namekarbari')?>"
               ></input><?php echo form_error('namekarbari'); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <label>password</label>
               <input  type="password" 
               class="form-control" id="kalameoboor" name="kalameoboor" 
               autocomplete="off"value="<?php echo set_value('kalameoboor')?>"
               ></input><?php echo form_error('kalameoboor'); ?>
            </div>

          <button></button>
        </form>



        </div>


        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1"></div>
        </div>



    <br/>




</div><!--end container-->      
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>boot/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>boot/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

my verifylogin controller:

```
    <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class VerifyLogin extends CI_Controller {

 function __construct()
 {
   parent::__construct();
   $this->load->model('user','',TRUE);
 }

 function index()
 {
   //This method will have the credentials validation
   $this->load->library('form_validation');

   $this->form_validation->set_rules('namekarbari', 'Username', 'trim|required');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('kalameoboor', 'Password', 'trim|required|callback_check_database');
   $this->form_validation->set_message('required'," %s ");
   $this->form_validation->set_message('trim'," %s ");


   if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
   {
     //Field validation failed.  User redirected to login page
     $this->load->view('login_view');
   }
   else
   {
     //Go to private area
     redirect('home', 'refresh');
   }
   }
   }?>
```

I want to redirect to different page from verifylogin.
thanks...

Comment: Please tag and include the coding language you are using in your question, also provide what you have currently tried. Stack overflow is a code help service not a code writing one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try grabbing the id of the button that was click, pass it via ajax and insert it in to a session, after login use  **if** and **else statement** or **switch statement** to redirect the user base on the value of the session.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `redirect('home', 'refresh');`

redirect with

```
redirect("<controller name>/<function name>");
```